# How to init a Tkinter canvas dependent on a main Tkinter window

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I am new to programing and am currently trying to do a program that draws graphs for affine functions (functions under the form f(x)=ax+b) with the Tkinter python library. I am doing a class called graph but when I want to init the canvas object it must be dependent to a frame. How can I init the main frame and a canvas object inside of a class? Here is the code:

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, a="", b="", dimensions=None, graduation=None, graph=tkinter.Tk(), graphing_area=tkinter.Canvas(graph, height=500, width=500)):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.dimensions = dimensions
        self.graduation = graduation
        self.graph = graph
        self.graphing_area = graphing_area
```

Comment: Make sure that you call `tkinter.Tk()` exactly once. That doesn't just create the root window, it also creates an instance of the Tcl interpreter that controls the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initiate values of graph and graphing_area outside arguments section. If you want option to set graph as function parameter set `graph` parameter to `None` by default and set `self.graph` to `graph` only if value is different that `None`.

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, a="", b="", dimensions=None, graduation=None, graph=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.dimensions = dimensions
        self.graduation = graduation
        if not graph:
            self.graph = tkinter.Tk()
        else:
            self.graph = graph
        self.graphing_area = tkinter.Canvas(self.graph, height=500, width=500)
```